Recalculate Roll breaks IK foot controls and character's legs
Blender 4.2.1

My paste flipped wasn't working


Trying to make it work, in Object Mode, I selected the armature, Ctrl + A and applied Rotation & Scale. Then, in Edit Mode, I selected all bones, ⇧ Shift + N (Recalculate Roll) and View Axis.
Doing that, I was now able to paste flipped, but my character's leg and IK foot controls broke.


Well, if the IK controls were based on the old messed up rotations and bone roll then of course they are broken now and have to be made new.
